# How do I automate Redis cache clearing once deployment occurs?

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I need to implement a way to clear the redis cache from the composer.json file once a deployment occurs. The snc redis bundle command is this:

```
namespace Snc\RedisBundle\Command;
/**
* Symfony command to execute redis flushall
*
*/
class RedisFlushallCommand extends RedisBaseCommand
{
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected function configure()
{
    parent::configure();
    $this->setName('redis:flushall')
        ->setDescription('Flushes the redis database using the redis flushall command');
}
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected function executeRedisCommand()
{
    if ($this->proceedingAllowed()) {
        $this->flushAll();
    } else {
        $this->output->writeln('<error>Flushing cancelled</error>');
    }
}
/**
 * Flushing all redis databases
 */
private function flushAll()
{
    $this->redisClient->flushall();
    $this->output->writeln('<info>All redis databases flushed</info>');
}
}
```

How do I include this in the `composer.json` file in the root file of the source code? I know there's probably a very easy way of doing this, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own composer script handler:

```
// src/AppBundle/ScriptHandler.php
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

class ScriptHandler
{
    public static function clearRedisCache()
    {    
        (new Application(new \AppKernel('dev', true)))
            ->get('redis:flushall')
            ->run(new ArrayInput(['--client' => 'YOURCLIENT']), new ConsoleOutput());
    }
}
```

Then register it in your composer.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "AppBundle\\ScriptHandler::clearRedisCache"
        // ...
     ]
}
```

You can try it using the following command:

```
$ composer run-script post-install-cmd
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly thank you so much for your help I really really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Could you accept the answer please ? It needs a click on the green check